# Create a trigger for making a single audit table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-delete

How do I create a trigger in Microsoft SQL server to keep a track of all deleted data of any table existing in the database into a single audit table? I do not want to write trigger for each and every table in the database. There will only be once single audit table which keeps a track of all the deleted data of any table.

For example:

If a data is deleted from a person table, get all the data of that person table and store it in an XML format in an audit table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a trigger for all tables in a SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865949/how-to-create-a-trigger-for-all-tables-in-a-sql-server-database)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please check my solution that I tried to describe at [SQL Server Log Tool for Capturing Data Changes](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/log-data-changes-using-change-data-capture-for-sql-server-2005.aspx)

The solution is build on creating trigger on selected tables dynamically to capture data changes (after insert, update, delete) and store those in a general table.

Then a job executes periodically and parses data captured and stored in this general table. After data is parsed it will be easier for humans to understand and see easily which table field is changed and its old and new values

I hope this proposed solution helps you for your own solution,

Comment: Link is dead, so this answer is now useless because the contents of the linked page was not included in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for warning JK, the link is now working with downloads of database backup and SQL script files included